# How to send a cookie with a unique value for each request?

Tags: cookies, csrf

**Context:**
In order to prevent CSRF attacks, I am following this basic approach:

- Generate a UUID at the front end itself for EVERY request
- Send this UUID via a cookie and request header to the backend.
- Backend will compare both the received UUIDs.
- If they match, it's a legit request otherwise it isn't.

**Problem I am facing:**
Since I am using the same cookie name with a different value(UUID) for each request, the browser seems to be sending the same cookie with the same UUID for the backend requests that are being sent in PARALLEL(Race Condition?). That's causing the UUID mismatch at the backend.

**Possible Solution:**
I can append the UUID to the cookie name itself. That way it would be a unique cookie name for each request.
Since I am sending a custom header as well, I can use that custom header to identify the cookie that belongs to the current request because I might receive multiple such cookies that would have been set by other requests.

**Question:**
Is there any other elegant solution to this problem?